# How to add member group tag to parametric field or case class field in scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

In Scaladoc, we can group class members using `@group` tag, taking example from [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L139)

```scala
/**
 * Retrieve the single value of a type with a unique inhabitant.
 * @group utilities
 */
@inline def valueOf[T](implicit vt: ValueOf[T]): T = vt.value
```

But I fail to see how to attach group tag to value members that are defined as
parametric field in (case) class's constructor parameter list.

For example,

```scala
/**
 * How to add @group tag for `x` and `y`?
 */
case class A(
  x: Int,
  y: Int,
)

/**
 * Similarly?
 */
class B(
  val x: Int,
  val y: Int,
)
```

`x` and `y` are essentially value members in those classes, and therefore in principle should be able to be grouped like normal class members, shouldn't they?